# Doesn't want to reference hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I'm having an issue with perl , and i really don't know why it is happening...
The problem is that :

```
sub rem_word{
    my ($self,$word) = @_;
    my $dic = $self;

    my @word = split(//,$word);
    my $count ; 
    my $first = 1;

    for my $letter(@word){
            $count = scalar (keys %$dic);

            #$dic = $dic->{$letter};

            if($dic->{$letter}){
                    print "ELEMENTOS KEYS : $count\n";
                    $dic = $dic->{letter};
            }
            print "WOOT COUNT: $count HASH: $dic\n";
    }
}
```

If i put the instruction "$dic = $dic->{letter}" in my "if" ... It seems that it isn't adding ... But, If i put before my if, it will add and continue  my loop...

Results ( before if):

```
WOOT COUNT: 3 HASH: HASH(0x7f88308361b8)
WOOT COUNT: 2 HASH: HASH(0x7f883088eb28)
WOOT COUNT: 2 HASH: HASH(0x7f8830832648)
WOOT COUNT: 2 HASH: HASH(0x7f88308f8060)
WOOT COUNT: 1 HASH: HASH(0x7f88308ff6f0)
```

Results ( inside if):

```
WOOT COUNT: 3 HASH:
WOOT COUNT: 0 HASH: HASH(0x7fb6918018c8)
WOOT COUNT: 0 HASH: HASH(0x7fb6918018c8)
WOOT COUNT: 0 HASH: HASH(0x7fb6918018c8)
WOOT COUNT: 0 HASH: HASH(0x7fb6918018c8)
```

And seriously ... I don't understand why it is giving me that result ... When apparently , for me , it's almost the same thing !
Gratefully,

Damien

Comment: What this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil I *think* OP is attempting to build a trie, but you are right: a dump of the expected data structure + corresponding test case would be most helpful.

Comment: Instead of this: `$dic = $dic->{letter}`. Don't you mean this: `$dic = $dic->{$letter}`? Missing dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't do that :

`my @word = split(//,$word);`

And then, there is the following, which is why this code doesn't do what you want :

`$dic = $dic->{letter};`

So `$dic` is a ref to a hash and now you give it a value of that hash.

Don't give the same name to different variables, even if they are not the same type. It will lead to confusion.

```
sub rem_word{
    my ($self,$word) = @_;
    my $dic = $self;

    my @lword = split(//,$word);
    my $count ; 
    my $first = 1;

    for my $letter(@lword){
            $count = scalar (keys %$dic);
            my $found ; 
            if($dic->{$letter}){
                    print "ELEMENTOS KEYS : $count\n";
                    $found = $dic->{$letter};
            }
            print "WOOT COUNT: $count HASH: $found\n";
    }
}
```

edit : fixed $letter as noted by @FMc

Comment: i think i must get out for a little ... thanks for the response ! :)
It's harder when perl doesn't say anything when there is a problem (which was obvious by the way):f